# HTML5 Video: autoplay not working in lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video, lightbox

I am using html5 video tag for displaying video in a lightbox. The video itself works fine. But when i try to autoplay it when someone opens the lightbox i fail.
Here is the javascript code i am using.

**HTML to trigger lightbox which is working fine.**

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-blue lightbox btnlb">Watch the full video</a>
```

**HTML of video tag which is also working fine.**

```
<video id="lbvideo" width="960" height="540">
    <source src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/videos/pinkgirl.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/videos/pinkgirl.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

**Javascript code for autlplaying video on click of lightbox. Not working as expected.**

```
$(".btnlb").click(function(e){
        var myVideo = document.getElementById("lbvideo"); 
        myVideo.play();
});
```

I have also tried using **timeout** after click, **but that did not work**.

```
$(".btnlb").click(function(e){
        setTimeout(function() {
        var myVideo = document.getElementById("lbvideo"); 
        myVideo.play();
        console.log(myVideo);
        }, 5000);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After working on this for a few hours, i found an alternative that did everything in minutes. I used afterglow which is a super easy to integrate HTML5 video player. With this simple setup i was all set and it looked really good.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>afterglow player</title>
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/afterglowplayer@1.x"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a class="afterglow" href="#myvideo">Launch lightbox</a>
    <video id="myvideo" width="960" height="540">
      <source type="video/mp4" src="/path/to/myvideo.mp4" />
    </video>
  </body>
<html>
```

Sharing in case it helps someone else and saves them some time. 
Happy Coding. :)